# An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Приложение падает в етом методе :

```
private void getContact(){
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            String name;
            String phone;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                if (dublicatContact(phone)) {
                    dbHelperContact.addContact(new Contacts(name, phone));
                } else {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is empty");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is empty");
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

с ошибкой `An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

Метод запускаю с AsynTask .

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=27143, uid=10092 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
   at com.sannacode.Fragments.FragmentContact.getContact(FragmentContact.java:145)
   at com.sannacode.Fragments.FragmentContact.access$300(FragmentContact.java:32)
   at com.sannacode.Fragments.FragmentContact$AsinkContact.doInBackground(FragmentContact.java:178)
   at com.sannacode.Fragments.FragmentContact$AsinkContact.doInBackground(FragmentContact.java:167)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Пермишн `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` в манифесте есть? А в рантайме запрашиваете его?

Comment: Спасибо, забьл  за пермишн

Comment: @post_zeew, Надо бы в ответ сие написать, чтобы статистику по вопросам не портить)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите стек-трейс, там подробно описана причина возникшей у Вас проблемы:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=27143, uid=10092 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

Скорее всего у Вас отсутствует разрешение `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` в манифесте, или же Вы используете `API 23+`, но не запрашиваете данное разрешение в рантайме (а нужно, так как оно относится к категории [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups)).